# How do I set up last.fm scrobbling with pianobar?

Tags: pianobar

I just [read about](http://lifehacker.com/5713551/pianobar-is-a-flash+free-pandora-player-inside-your-terminal) this command line Pandora player called [pianobar](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pianobar)

It works great but the [homepage](http://6xq.net/html/00/17.html) says "last.fm scrobbling (using an external scrobbler)"

Any one ever set this up before?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. First you'll need an external scrobbler. I recommend [`scrobbler-helper`](http://search.cpan.org/~roam/Audio-Scrobbler-0.01/bin/scrobbler-helper), which is written in Perl and available via [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/).

   ```
   sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Audio::Scrobbler'
   ```
2. Configure pianobar to use external scrobbler.

   Skip the next two steps if you already have a `~/.config/pianobar/config`.

   - Create the configuration directory for pianobar,

     ```
     mkdir -p ~/.config/pianobar
     ```
   - Copy the example config file,

     ```
     cp /usr/share/doc/pianobar/contrib/config-example ~/.config/pianobar/config
     ```
   - Now in `~/.config/pianobar/config`, remove the `#` from the beginning of this line:

     ```
     #event_command = /home/user/.config/pianobar/eventcmd
     ```

     and replace `user` with your actual username. This sets the path of the script that will be run every time you finish playing a song.
   - `~/.config/pianobar/eventcmd` doesn't exist yet, so download this [script](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/544112/) to your Desktop. That script is the same as the one found in `/usr/share/doc/pianobar/contrib/eventcmd.sh`, but with some lines that required extra packages commented out. Once you have downloaded it, rename it to `eventcmd` then run the following commands:

     ```
     cp ~/Desktop/eventcmd ~/.config/pianobar/eventcmd
     chmod +x ~/.config/pianobar/eventcmd
     ```
3. Configure `scrobbler-helper`,

   `scrobbler-helper` needs to know your Last.fm account and password.

   - Create a file `~/.scrobbler-helper.conf` and paste the following into it:

     ```
     [global]
     username=USERNAME
     password=PASSWORD
     ```

     replacing `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` with your actual Last.fm username and password.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution: There is a Gtk application called [Pithos](http://kevinmehall.net/p/pithos/) that is built on libpiano (i.e., it uses the same backend as pianobar). You can set up last.fm scrobbling in the preferences.

Of course, if you prefer a command-line player this doesn't help you very much. But if what you're really looking for is a non-flash, desktop-based Pandora player, this may be perfect for you.

Answer (score 2):

`lastfmsubmitd` is cool, because it will queue up scrobbles if the network is down.

Copying and pasting the following into bash should get you up and running.

```
sudo apt-get install pianobar lastfmsubmitd #install requirements
sudo usermod -a G lastfm $USER              #use `lastfmsubmitd` setup group
sudo /etc/init.d/lastfmsubmitd restart      #restart `lastfmsubmitd`
mkdir ~/.config/pianobar                    #setup config environment
cd ~/.config/pianobar
cp /usr/share/doc/pianobar/contrib/eventcmd.sh .
ed eventcmd.sh <<"EOF"                      #Add `lastfmsubmitd` support
10a
        songfinish)
                if [ -n "$songDuration" ] &&
                   [ $(echo "scale=4; ($songPlayed/$songDuration*100)>50" | bc) -eq 1 ] &&
                   [ "$rating" -ne 2 ]; then
                        /usr/lib/lastfmsubmitd/lastfmsubmit --artist "$artist" --title "$title" --album "$album" --length "$((songDuration/1000))"
                fi
                ;;
.
wq
EOF
echo "event_command = $HOME/.config/pianobar/eventcmd.sh" >> config
```

The `eventcmd.sh` part of the script is from [Arnold French](http://ench.info/2010/12/setting-pianobar-lastfmsubmitd)

**EDIT:** You may have to `chmod +x eventcmd.sh`.